# How to programatically save arkit object in .dae format

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, arkit

I am working on an app the creates a 3d mesh of users face. I am successful in generating data of a users face.

I want to programatically save this data in .dae format so that i could export my .dae file, edit that in 3d softwares like blender, and than further import it in my iphone and display that file in sceneview.

Long story short i want programatically save the data in .dae format. I am not able to find anything on internet about this.

If there could be another approach then please tell me.

Comment: Hello Jagjot, I want to do the same but couldn't find anything on the web, can you help me if you've done it?

Answer (score 7):

SceneKit doesn’t natively read or write DAE format in iOS. (SceneKit reads/writes DAE only in macOS. When you ship a DAE in your app’s bundle resources, Xcode converts it to an iOS-optimized format at build time.)

Your best bet for exporting a mesh to common file formats from iOS is [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio). That framework supports several formats, but not DAE. If you’re just looking to output the `ARFaceGeometry` mesh generated by ARKit, you don’t really need a format more complicated than OBJ, and Model I/O does that.

The gist:

1. Create an [`MDLMesh`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh) from your vertex/index data. That’ll require [`MDLMeshBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmeshbuffer)s for the vertex and texture coordinate data, and [`MDLSubmesh`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlsubmesh)es for the triangle index data. Or, if you already have the mesh in SceneKit, convert it with [`MDLMesh(scnGeometry:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh/1419853-init).
2. Create an empty [`MDLAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset), and [add](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391634-add) your mesh to it as a child object.
3. [Export](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391036-export) the asset to a file. The filename extension of the URL you provide for writing the asset to determines the file format for export, so use a “.obj” filename if you want to write an OBJ file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to export the mesh file and edit that in 3d softwares like blender. Is this approach that you gave suitable for that?

Comment: hello rickster, I am trying to do the same; exporting a mesh programmatically into Obj. file and I can't find anything on the web. Is it possible for you to give some more information on how I can do it, or maybe share some resources with me?

Comment: If using  `MDLMesh(scnGeometry:)` the way to import the header is `import SceneKit.ModelIO`

Comment: is there any method export ARFaceGeometry with actual face size??

Comment: I'm stumped on this, would love some example code, here's a question I asked related to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475201/save-arfacegeometry-to-obj-file

Answer (score 3):

you can try the code below:

```
  let scene2 = sceneView.scene
  let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
  let timeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
  let filename = String(format: "test_%d.dae", timeInterval)
  let exportUrl = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(filename)
  scene2.write(to: exportUrl, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil);
```

Comment: Hey Can you please tell me can we also save the facial expressions while exporting into file.after that using the same file with the mesh replicate the same expressions.?

Can you guide me on how to do this?

Comment: As of iOS 16, the code in this answer now exports an SCN file (with a DAE file extension). Think it did previously work.