# ARKit - Capture textures for provided environment mesh using Lidar

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, lidar

I'm trying to create environment mesh with textures, the mesh has been built successfully but not sure how to the store captured textures to apply to the mesh later. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733708/texture-armeshgeometry-from-arkit-camera-frame) as we are creating a geometry for each anchor at the final state of scan, I suppose we need to store each frame texture for corresponding anchor with help of ARSession delegate.

The way textures are recording:

```
//Create a dictionary to store textures corresponding to each anchor 
private var anchors = [UUID: UIImage]()

//Store every new anchor with the current frame image
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    guard let cameraImage = captureCamera() else { return }
    anchors.forEach { anchor in
        self.anchors[anchor.identifier] = cameraImage
    }
}
    
//In case of an anchor update, texture needs to be updated too(not sure it's necessary or not)
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    guard let cameraImage = captureCamera() else { return }
    anchors.forEach { anchor in
        self.anchors[anchor.identifier] = cameraImage
    }
}

//Remove every removed anchor to free up the memory    
func session(_ session: ARSession, didRemove anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    anchors.forEach { anchor in
        self.anchors.removeValue(forKey: anchor.identifier)
    }
}

//Capture current camera frame image
func captureCamera() -> UIImage? {
    guard let frame = metalARSession.currentFrame else {return nil}

    let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage

    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

    let context = CIContext(options:nil)
    guard let cameraImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent) else {return nil}

    return UIImage(cgImage: cameraImage)
}
```

In rest of the code I have created a MDLAsset and export it as an OBJ file, also textures are saved on storage and texture coordinates are calculated too. Now how can I apply these textures to my OBJ file?

Comment: Can you please share the current state of your work, maybe some GitHub repo? Would be grateful !

Comment: Not done yet, but  it has done using c++. you can take look at : https://github.com/nmoehrle/mvs-texturing

Comment: Any success yet?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398706/how-to-create-3d-scanning-ios-app-using-photogrammetry-or-lidar/76207146#76207146